# Device Registration Not Shown in Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, ionic2, azure-notificationhub, azure-api-apps

I have an **Ionic App** on Android device. My server-side is Microsoft **Azure Cloud** consisting of various **Api Apps** and Azure **Notification Hub**.

One of the Api App is configured with my Notification Hub. I have also setup Google (GCM) Api Key.

In the app, upon successful authentication against Azure AD I am initiating Device Registration for Push Notification.

It appears the device registration is successful as I am getting a Registration ID in my app. **However, to check if the same Registration ID is now stored/available in Notification Hub when I go to `Visual Studio 2017 -> Service Explorer -> Notification Hubs -> MyNotificationHub -> Device Registrations`, there is no device registered.**

The "Test Send" is also not working (i.e., the push notification is not coming to device). I tired it from Visual Studio as well as Azure Portal. This I guess is because the Registration ID has not been saved in the Notification Hub.

Would appreciate if somebody can provide some pointers on how to get it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried going through [Azure Notification Hubs - Diagnosis guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer)?

Comment: @NikitaG. - thanks for the reply. No, I didn't know they added that in the documentation since the last time I went through the documentation. I will go through it. Hope it helps me resolve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @NikitaG. - the Diagnosis Guidelines mainly talks about sending/receiving Push Notification. Mine is a different situation. In my case, I am not seeing the registered device in my Notification Hub. I got the Registration ID in my app therefore I am assuming the Registration was successful. But then, do not see the same Registration ID when I open my Notification Hub in Visual Studio and go to "Device Registrations" tab. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: If you step into the code, does the registration call go through successfully? If so, could you double check that the account/subscription that you use in the code is the same that you use in Service Bus Explorer?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?